# how to enable word-wrap on xcode issues/ errors

Tags: xcode, macos, navigator

In xcode when my errors are listed i cannot read the complete string. In issue navigator also i am unable to read complete string, is there an option to enable word-wrap or is there a shortcut key for it. I work mostly on small screen this is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the middle of the bar on the leftmost window. Click the exclamation point, this brings you to the *Issue Viewer* which allows you to easily navigate through all your issues. You can also right click on an issue and ask it to goto the issue navigator.

For more tips type *viewing issues in the issue navigator* in the help bar and their is a tutorial

You can also just hover your mouse above the issue for a more complete description, this only works if the message is actually cut off with an ellipsis.

Comment: Hovering over item does the job, but in issue navigator i have to manually hover on each error/ warning to get the full description, i could not find any word-wrap option. I have to resize the issue navigator/ and log navigator too to read error descriptions, if still some are longer the option is to hover on one by one. Word-wrap right in the window(s) would have been better option like in Visual Studio

Comment: @user651717 i doubt there is another way to do it since the advice i gave is in xcodes own documentation sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to the last tab in the leftmost panel, to pull up the Log Navigator (or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>). You can then click on your most recent build log and examine the results there and you'll see the gory detail.

If you like that log view on your small screen, you can also tell Xcode to automatically pull that up if there are any warnings or errors by going to "Preferences" and looking at the behaviors tab:

[image: build behaviors]